# How to create a rectangular grid with custom start point and step value

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, grid, camera-calibration

I'm working on a project where I need to calibrate to cameras. As you know one needs to define a plane grid points in the 3D-world and find their correspondences on the image plane. Therefore, the first camera has the following 3D_grid points:

```
mport cv2 as cv 
import numpy as np

WPoints_cam1 = np.zeros((9*3,3), np.float64)
WPoints_cam1[:,:2] = np.mgrid[0:9,0:3].T.reshape(-1,2)*0.4
print(WPoints_cam1)

[[0.  0.  0. ]# world coordinate center
[0.4 0.  0. ]
[0.8 0.  0. ]
[1.2 0.  0. ]
[1.6 0.  0. ]
[2.  0.  0. ]
[2.4 0.  0. ]
[2.8 0.  0. ]
[3.2 0.  0. ]
[0.  0.4 0. ]
[0.4 0.4 0. ]
[0.8 0.4 0. ]
[1.2 0.4 0. ]
[1.6 0.4 0. ]
[2.  0.4 0. ]
[2.4 0.4 0. ]
[2.8 0.4 0. ]
[3.2 0.4 0. ]
[0.  0.8 0. ]
[0.4 0.8 0. ]
[0.8 0.8 0. ]
[1.2 0.8 0. ]
[1.6 0.8 0. ]
[2.  0.8 0. ]
[2.4 0.8 0. ]
[2.8 0.8 0. ]
[3.2 0.8 0. ]]
```

[image: Grid]
As seen above the first grid (for the first camera) starts from the defined reference 3D_point **(0,0,0)** and ends by the point **(3.2,0.8 0)** with a **constant offset of 0.4** and 9x3 dimension

Note that all Z coordinates were put to Z=0 (Zhengyou Zhang calibration)

**Now my question is**, as I need to define a second grid(for the second camera) that also refers to the defined 3D_coordinate center (0,0,0), I need to define a grid that **starts from (3.6,0,0) and ends with (6.8,0.8,0)** with the **same offset 0.4** and has a dimension 9x3

I believe this is easy to do. However I can't think out of the box due to my beginner level of experience.

Would appreciate for some help and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can scale each column like this:

```
np.mgrid[0:8, 0:3].T.reshape(-1,2) * np.array([(7.8 - 3.6) / 7, 0.4]) + np.array([3.6, 0])
```

or combine it into scaling matrix like this (and then add on a vector for the translation)

```
np.mgrid[0:8, 0:3].T.reshape(-1,2) @ np.array([[(7.8 - 3.6) / 7, 0], [0, 0.4]]).T + np.array([3.6, 0])
```

regarding where `(7.8 - 3.6) / 7` comes from, the numerator should be self evident. The denominator is the same but for your original dimensions. With `0:8` the max is `7` and the min is `0` so the denominator becomes `7 - 0`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It actually works, except that the step is 0.6 which is supposed to be 0.4.@Dan

Comment: @k.jbaili how can the step be 0.4 if it is 8 rows and ranges from 3.6 to 7.8? That is impossible. If you are setting your range, then you can either set your steps size or set your number of rows. If you are setting the step size then it is trivial `np.mgrid[3.6:77.8+0.4:0.4, 0:1.2:0.4]`. But in your question, you specified 8 rows so hence a step of 0.6.

Comment: I'm so sorry I made a huge mistake. The second grid should be 0:9 for x dimension and 0:3 for the y dimension and thus ranges from 3.6 to 6.8. I will correct the question.@Dan

Comment: It won't make a difference though - just change the `7.8` in my answer to `6.8` and change `0:8` to `0:9` if you need an extra row. It will give you what you need.

Comment: you're write. it makes no different. I should have clarified that i want the step size to be 0.4. Thanks I really appreciate it.@Dan

Comment: I've mentioned you on another question which. I hope you could give me some piece of info. Thanks alot. @Dan